# How to train universal sentence encoder from scratch

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use universal sentence encoder but the problem is that Google's pretrained versions doesn't support my language (not even multilingual version: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3)

Is there any tutorial or way how to train my own universal sentence encoder from scratch with my own corpus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the issue opened here(https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/36) it seems that the model was not released to open source. You need to build it by yourself or fine-tuned to specific task.

Comment: Is there a similar model available which provides the functionality of training it as well as working similar to Universal Sentence Encoder.?

Comment: Try transformer based models (find here some docs https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)